# Style sheet not loading

Tags: css, asp.net, iis

I have setup a local website on a new IIS server 8, but the style sheet is not loaded.

master page is referencing the style sheet as

```
href="/HeadOffice/Styles/HeadOfficeCalendar.css"
```

as in:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/HeadOffice/Styles/HeadOfficeCalendar.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Site home page is

```
//localhost/TESTFESTOON/HeadOffice/home.aspx
```

physical path for the styles folder is

```
E:\inetpub\ForRelease\HeadOffice\Styles
```

some of the images are also not loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag the CSS file from Solution Explorer to the code view of your master page and see if that fixes it.

Alternatively, try this syntax:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="<%= ResolveUrl("~") %>HeadOffice/Styles/HeadOfficeCalendar.css" 
        type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Comment: Please note, i am not running it with visual studio, i created the build files and deployed it to a server, but for test purposes i am running it on local host rather than a web address

Comment: thanks that worked, but i noticed something needs to be done with the links as well  the website should have TESTFESTOON in the url, but when i click on the links TESTFESTOON disappears   URL: http://localhost/TESTFESTOON/HeadOffice/home.aspx    LINK URL : http://localhost/HeadOffice/ReactiveJobs/Summary.aspx

Comment: Show me your actual link, and not a share?

Comment: i have hard coded the actual link and it works  http://localhost/TESTFESTOON/HeadOffice/ReactiveJobs/Summary.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax, this will generate the correct URL

```
     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
    href='<%= Server.ResolveClientUrl("~/HeadOffice/Styles/HeadOfficeCalendar.css") %>' />
```